# Is it allowed for a French company to only accept French passports for registration for a service

Tags: european-union, discrimination, france

La Poste has an online identification system called "*l'identité numérique*" for which registration requires a French passport or "Titre de séjour français" [see this](https://aide.lidentitenumerique.laposte.fr/kb/guide/fr/qui-peut-creer-une-identite-numerique-la-poste-x2Q0shoa9U/Steps/101476).

As a non-French EU citizen, Bob does not have any of these documents. Bob does not require a "*Titre de séjour français*" to work in France. I'm wondering if Bob could still get one but clearly no one would do this just to have access to this service and this effectively bars me from using *l'identité numérique*.

I would think this breaks EU laws that enforce equal rights for EU citizens of different nationalities.

Is this indeed illegal? Is there any remedy that Bob could receive?

Comment: You probably have some form of registration certificate, but that is not a form of identification card. A permanent residence card is I believe possible after 5 years. But there is no french document for eu residents less than 5 years. Someone at *La Poste* seems to have overlooked this combination.